# Environment variable expansion syntax in the arguments of Visual Studio's 2017 "Browse With" web browser edit dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, browser, visual-studio-2017, environment-variables

This dialog here is driving me a little crazy.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Browse With dialog, an environment variable highlighted in its arguments section, which doesn't get expanded when the browser configured in the Program value is executed]

Is there any way to expand environment variable in the arguments syntax?

I've tried:

```
%APPDATA%
${APPDATA}
${env:APPDATA}
(${APPDATA})
```